# pyspark new column with select where

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create 2 additional columns to my dataframe that are based on a calculation involving one column dividing with itself with a condition on another column.

I have a working example with SQL transformation but need to rewrite it in pyspark equvilent and can't get it right. What I have so far:

```py
%python

data = [("AUD", 7.1), ("EUR", 11.2), ("USD", 9.1)]
cols = ["Currency", "RateSEK"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
df.show()

+--------+-------+
|Currency|RateSEK|
+--------+-------+
|     AUD|    7.1|
|     EUR|   11.2|
|     USD|    9.1|
+--------+-------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempdf")
```

The above is what I have in pyspark so far.
The below is the SQL code that I want to achieve with pyspark:

```sql
%sql
SELECT 
*,
RateSEK / (SELECT RateSEK FROM tempdf WHERE Currency = 'EUR') AS RateEur,
RateSEK / (SELECT RateSEK FROM tempdf WHERE Currency = 'USD') AS RateUSD
FROM
tempdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result of the subqueries using `.head()`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'RateEur', 
    F.col('RateSEK') / df.filter("Currency = 'EUR'").head()['RateSEK']
).withColumn(
    'RateUSD', 
    F.col('RateSEK') / df.filter("Currency = 'USD'").head()['RateSEK']
)

df2.show()
+--------+-------+------------------+------------------+
|Currency|RateSEK|           RateEur|           RateUSD|
+--------+-------+------------------+------------------+
|     AUD|    7.1|0.6339285714285714|0.7802197802197802|
|     EUR|   11.2|               1.0|1.2307692307692308|
|     USD|    9.1|            0.8125|               1.0|
+--------+-------+------------------+------------------+
```